# Many-to-one cascade delete NHibernate results in RESTRICT (MySQL 5)

Tags: nhibernate, cascade, many-to-one, cascading-deletes

I've a simple `category` class. Each `category` can have zero or more children of type `category`. Therefore I have chosen to register the parent of a `category`, which can be null or the id of another `category`. When a `category` is deleted, all its children (of type `category`) must be deleted as well.

When the schema of the table is created by NHibernate, the foreign key exists, but `On Delete:` is set to `RESTRICT`. 
NOTE: When I manually change `On Delete:` to `CASCADE` all works as expected.

I've read that this is a wrong approach to relate the child to a parent. I do not see why. Hence, it works. But NHibernate doesn't configure the `On Delete` how I would like to.

I've read about inverse collections and bags, and using separate tables. But I am confused about what my approach should be.

How would one achieve the on `delete cascade` with this `category` class, and why?

My mapping looks like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="BackEnd"
                   namespace="BackEnd.Models">
  <class name="Category">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <many-to-one class="Category" name="Parent" cascade="delete"/>
    <property name="Description" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can children also have children that can also have children etc etc?

Comment: Yes they can. Each category can only have 1 parent (ParentId column in databaes). But each parent can have more child categories. So multiple levels possible.

Comment: I am now looking into mapping the children categories in a IList, instead of loading the parent category with eager/lazy loading upon loading a category. All examples on the net are with two tables. But why the heck would I need two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how its possible to map a parent child relationship in the same table, listing all childeren to your object, and deleting all childs when a parent is deleted.

I finally got this by trial and error. It took me 15 attempts.

```
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                       assembly="BackEnd"
                       namespace="BackEnd.Models">
      <class name="Category">
        <id name="Id">
          <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Name" />
        <property name="ParentId" />
        <bag name="Children" table="Category" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
          <key column="ParentId" on-delete="cascade"/>
          <one-to-many class="Category"/>
        </bag>
        <property name="Description" />
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the code for the class I use.

```
/// <summary>
/// The ModelBase takes care of the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functionalities for each derived class.
/// public functions here must be virtual, read this: http://thatextramile.be/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/
/// This is an abstract class as it has no purpose on its own.
/// </summary>
public abstract class ModelBase<T>
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The id by which this transient object is related to a persistent object in database.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ulong Id { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Many objects, like categories, issues, etc, can have a parent of the same type
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ulong ParentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The childeren of this object, if any
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IList<T> Children
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor only available for derived classes.
    /// </summary>
    protected ModelBase()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates or updates this object in database.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void CreateOrUpdate()
    {
        using(ISession Session = Gate.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            Session.SaveOrUpdate(((T)((Object)this)));
            Session.Flush();
            Session.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes this object from database
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Delete()
    {
        using (ISession Session = Gate.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            Session.Delete(((T)((Object)this))); //Needs to be casted as the type of the top most class, or it will fail to get its properties.
            Session.Flush();
            Session.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a persistent object (from database) in to a transienst object (variable).
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="Id">The Id of the object by which it is known in database.</param>
    /// <returns>A strong typed object.</returns>
    public static T Load(ulong Id)
    {
        /* TODO: Lazy loading only possible when sessinos remains open.
         * Solve this by adding some kind of OnDispose event that automatically closes the connection when the object is disposed.
         */
        //using (ISession Session = Gate.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        //{
        //    ModelObject = Session.Load<T>(Id);
        //    Session.Close();
        //}
        ISession Session = Gate.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        return Session.Load<T>(Id);
    }
}
```

And finally the category class that is derived from the base class

```
/// <summary>
/// A part can be categorized, under one or more, categories.
/// Each category is an instance of this class.
/// </summary>
public class Category : ModelBase<Category>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the category that is displayed to the user.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }    

    /// <summary>
    /// A description of what this category is about.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual String Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The constructor creates a new category object.
    /// </summary>
    public Category()
    {
    }
}
```